# Use {{ token }} from Flask route in Jinja2 set statement

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask route that renders a template and passes a parameter like this:

```
return render_template('index.html', pid='token')
```

In the view, I'd like to use the `pid` in a `{% set %}` or `{% if %}` statement as:

```
{% set active_menu = {{ pid }} | default('default_token') %}
....

{% if id == active_menu %}
    do_something
{% endif %}
```

Alternative I tried:

```
...
{% if id == {{ pid }} %}
    do_something
{% endif %}
```

But it fails to compile with error `Expression expected` for the line `id == {{ pid }}`. Is it not possible to assign `{{ some_token }}` to a `{% set %}` in `Jinja2`? What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `{% if id == pid %}`?

Comment: Oh I was just editing the question. Yes! it worked for `pid` but I have a default that needs to go inside the `{% set %}`. I thought I have to always  use `{{ }}` to reference a passed variable.